# Compare two hashtable keys along with their values

Tags: java, jsp, hashmap, compare, hashtable

I am using Hashtables in JSP. I want to compare two Hashtable values and keys. First Hashtable contains question number(key) and user answer(value). Second Hash Table contains question number (key) and original answer (value). I want to check first if question number match then i want to check answer for same question number. I want simplest solution.I am a learner, not expert. :)

Comment: Can you please show , what you have tried so far ?

Comment: while(s.hasNext())
    { 
        Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) s.next();
       
            int v = (Integer)entry.getKey();
            String k = (String)entry.getValue();
        while(s1.hasNext())
        {
            Map.Entry entry1 = (Map.Entry) s1.next();
             int c = (Integer)entry1.getKey();
            String d = (String)entry1.getValue();
            
            if(v==c && k==d)
            {
                chkcount = chkcount + 1;
            }
            
            
        }
        
    }

Comment: I've tried diff diff ways as i saw on this website and others.

Comment: Please edit your code into the question (it's horrible as a comment) and explain in what way it doesn't do what you want. Ideally, show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. Looking at your code, you're *at least* comparing strings badly. Also, it would make life easier if you used generic collections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Actual Answers
        Map<Integer,String> first = new Hashtable<Integer, String>();
        first.put(1,"A");
        first.put(2,"B");
        first.put(3,"C");

        //User Answers
        Map<Integer,String> second = new Hashtable<Integer, String>();
        second.put(1,"A");
        second.put(2,"A");
        second.put(3,"A");
        checkAnswers(first,second);
}

        public static void checkAnswers(Map<Integer,String> first, Map<Integer,String> second){ 
            int chkcount = 0;
            for(Map.Entry<Integer,String> entry: second.entrySet()){
                String actualAnswer = first.get(entry.getKey());
                String givenAnswer = entry.getValue();
                if(givenAnswer != null && actualAnswer != null && givenAnswer.equals(actualAnswer)){
                    chkcount = chkcount + 1;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(chkcount);

        }
```